# Typesetting Kannada text using XeTeX

Tags: xetex, indic

I have been typesetting a Kannada for a while using `kanlel`. In the last couple of days I am trying to switch to `xetex`, but compiling even a simple text has been far from smooth. Since I couldn't find much help on the web I decided to post a question here.

Here is what I am trying to complile.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Script=Kannada]{Lohit Kannada}
\begin{document}
namUmxru maYsUru.\\
ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರು
\textbf{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\emph{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\end{document}
```

The following are the problems are I am facing.

1. It gets compiled, but there are a lot of errors. Error `kernel/command-already-defined` appears at various places.
2. There are a few warnings on the font. Examples include `Font 'Lohit Kannada' does not contain script 'Kannada'` and `Could not resolve font Lohit Kannada/I (it probably doesn't exist)`. I am sure I have the font.
3. In the output file, `namUmxru maYsUru` appear as boxes. The text given in Kannada language is rendered, but there is no hyphenation. `textbf` and `emph` are not giving the expected results.

Would appreciate any help in resolving these issues.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that all of the character in your MWE are typeset right?

Comment: Thanks for asking. There is a typo in the MWE: 'maYsuru' should have been 'meYsuru'. But that should not affect compilation.

Comment: I managed to solve the first of the three issues I mentioned. The problem was this: I had some of the style files in two places - one at the standard tex location, and the other at texmf. The issue disappeared after I removed the files from texmf folder.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing this 4.5-month old question only now. Here is some input that may get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont{Noto Sans Kannada}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}
\textenglish{namUmxru maYsUru.}
ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರು
\textbf{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\emph{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: screenshot of generated pdf]

Not everything is perfect. An explanation of some of the problems mentioned in the question:

---

The warning

> Font 'Lohit Kannada' does not contain script 'Kannada'

means that in the font 'Lohit Kannada', there are no OpenType features specific to script tag 'knda' (or perhaps 'knd2'). (I touched upon this in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336157/i-get-tofu-instead-of-lepcha-tibeto-burmese-script/336162#336162).) The fix is to change the line

> \setmainfont[Script=Kannada]{Lohit Kannada}

to just

> \setmainfont{Lohit Kannada}

because there are no script-specific features you wish to load. (The `Script=` is meant mainly for multilingual fonts that contain different font features for different scripts.)

---

The warning

> Could not resolve font Lohit Kannada/I (it probably doesn't exist)

is specifically about the italic variant (`/I`) of Lohit Kannada. It indeed probably doesn't exist. At least, fontspec was not able to find the font. (A possible reason is that Lohit Kannada is not in the now-standard OpenType format: see this post [Improving Kannada Fonts](http://aravindavk.in/blog/improving-kannada-fonts/) from 2013 and follow the links from there for more details.)

When compiling my above input with Noto Sans Kannada (which doesn't have an italic style), I get the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/NotoSansKannada(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/NotoSansKannada(0)/m/n' instead on input line 12
```

which is slightly more clear.

---

The reason the Latin-script text `namUmxru maYsUru` appears in boxes is because of the `\setmainfont`: the Lohit Kannada font does not contain glyphs for Latin characters, so for those characters you need to switch to an "English" font. (With `polyglossia` you can use `\textenglish` around such sections.)

To get hyphenation, you can use `polyglossia` and declare the language as Kannada with `\setmainlanguage{Kannada}`, which will load some hyphenation patterns specific to Kannada script. (Sort of. These aren't very smart, but seem to know not to break in the middle of a visual letter.)

For `\textbf` and `\emph` to work, your font needs to have bold and italic variants, and XeTeX (fontspec) needs to be able to find them.

---

The example output above with Noto Sans Kannada was still not perfect (as it doesn't have italics, plus I don't understand why the line lengths are different), so I tried switching to a different font, Kedage. Unfortunately this font seems to have an "empty" glyph for the hyphen character, so (short of editing the font to fix its hyphen), this is a hack, using a different character instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont[HyphenChar={+}]{Kedage}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}
\textenglish{namUmxru maYsUru.}
ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರುನಮ್ಮೂರುಮೈಸೂರು
\textbf{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\emph{ನಮ್ಮೂರು ಮೈಸೂರು.}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: screenshot with kedage used instead]

which may be preferable.

Comment: Awesome, it really helped my work.

Answer (score 1):

Noto Serif Kannada (google fonts better, bold do not work properly in xelatex). For bold/italics I am using Kedage (Mallige also available). Bold-Italics we have Mallige.

Noto Serif Kannada  ಬಳಸುವವರು ಮೊದಲು ಆನ್‌ಲೈನ್‌ನಲ್ಲಿ ಈ ಫಾಂಟ್‌ಗಳ .tfm, .pfb extension (Online conversion available) ಪಡೆಯಬೇಕು. ಇವನ್ನು texlive ಆದರೆ ಅದರ ಸಂಬಂಧಿತ ಫೈಲುಗಳಲ್ಲಿ texmf-dist font folder ಸೇರಿಸಿ ನಂತರ texmflsr run ಮಾಡಿದರೆ ಮಾತ್ರ ಕೆಲಸ ಮಾಡುತ್ತವೆ.

Comment: Pradeep could you expand on your answer to make it more comprehensive, as to why you think Noto fonts are better? I do think the same by the way, the latest versions also support english, so one does not need to keep switching between the languages. Also provide links for the Mallige font and online conversions and a full minimal. Are you a native speaker of Kannada? How about linebreaks? Do you use Babel, polyglossia or just break lines manually?

Comment: Also personally I recommend the use of LuaLaTeX for compiling as the harfbuzz shaping engine is getting better and the way to long term shaping of Indic fonts is promising.

Answer (score 0):

At present I am using this in xelatex:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf}[Script=Kannada, 
   BoldFont=NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf,
   BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2},
   SlantedFont={NotoSerifKannada-Light.ttf},
   SlantedFeatures={Fake`Slant=0.4},
   BoldItalicFont=NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf,
   BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=3,FakeSlant=0.3},
]
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{EBGaramond-Medium.ttf}
```

Sorry I found not much difference between Noto Sans Kannada and Noto Serif Kannada. Later fonts are slightly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Using fonts I found the following procedure that works for me in **Windows (texlive 2023)**

Get your .ttf converted into .pfb & .tfm fonts (available online)

place .ttf fonts in texmf-dist/fonts/trutype **folder**

place .tfm fonts in texmf-dist/fonts/tfm **folder**

place .pfb fonts in texmf-dist/fonts/type1 **folder**

Then I had run at texlive mktexlsr (but not sure it is required)

Comment: Something like this is only needed when using pdfTeX (`pdflatex`), not XeTeX (`xelatex`).

Comment: BTW thanks for coming back and sharing what's working for you, but do note that it's possible (and preferred) to edit your existing answer instead of adding a new answer each time.